# html-webpack-plugin injection and webpack causing continuous refresh

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm having an issue using html-webpack-plugin and webpack, where the html-webpack-plugin is injecting scripts into the body of `index.html`. This is apparently causing webpack to continuously refresh, and generate new files every time. First, how do I prevent this from happening, and second, is there a way to configure html-webpack-plugin to delete the scripts corresponding to webpack generated javascript files that no longer exist (in this case the out-of-date files corresponding to out`static/bundle-[hash].js` in the below configuration file)?

Here is the webpack configuration file:

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "static/bundle-[hash].js",
    },
    resolveLoader: {
    moduleExtensions: ['-loader']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'css-loader',
                query: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['static/bundle*.js']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) **You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for you, supply your own template**

So Either you can generate a HTML file by giving **filename** or you can pass a template like **index.html**

Answer (score 0):

In development, you should remove all hash in your filename to prevent this behavior!

Webpack can update old file with new content with hot reloading.